# Booking System to attend Interview session

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm currently doing recruitment system by using drupal 7.. In my system, the applicant can apply the job and HR admin can choose the capable candidate..

After HR admin shortlisted the capable candidate, the candidate can book the interview session that has been set by HR admin.

For example, the interview session is 7,8 and 9 June.. So the applicant can choose which date they want to attend..

is there any related module for this? I've found [Booking Time Slots](https://drupal.org/project/booking_timeslots) module. But it's only available for drupal 6 i guess.

Help me..

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [Drupal Recruit](https://drupal.org/project/recruit) ? Basic solution to allow people to apply (application is a Drupal entity, fieldable, created by the applicant who does not need to be logged in). Works great.

For the booking system, I would try to setup a session content type with date field and entity reference field to a "job" node. HR can create sessions for a particular job. Then I would use [Drupal Flag](https://drupal.org/project/flag) to allow applicants to choose (by flagging sessions nodes) a session when the HR shortlisted them. You'll have to deal with roles and permissions carefully I guess...

I recently used both of these D7 modules, with great satisfaction.

Good luck